# Хочу добавить ключ к словарю,но есть ньюанс

Tags: python

Имею вот такой вод словарик:

```
main = {'a':{'b':{},'c':{}}
```

И хочу добавить допустим к ключу 'b' какой либо ещё ключ со словарём (для дерева). И как я могу это сделать. Как я подозреваю это должно быть примерно так

```
main['a']['b']['c']['e'] = {}
```

Вот так,но мне нужно чтобы так можно было сделать с разными ключами,помогите!

P.S Может тут надо использовать цикл,пробовал так `main[(t for t in top)][newtop] = {}`
но не получилось.

Comment: А зачем вам это?

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы описали решаемую этим словариком задачу - возможно, получится найти решенее более элегантное чем то, что вы хотите

Answer (score 0):

Задача не до конца понятна, но Вам скорее всего нужна рекурсивная функция наподобие ниже:

```
def dict_access(dic):
    for key in dic:
        if isinstance(dic[key], dict):
            dict_access(dic[key])
        else:
            # что-нибудь, что вам надо
```